# Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder dispatching vuex actions fails

Tags: vuejs2, electron, vuex

I have a Vue Electron app created with Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder and I try to integrate vuex, having the following store structure
[image]

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { createPersistedState, createSharedMutations } from "vuex-electron";

import user from "./modules/user";

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

Vue.use(Vuex);

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log(user);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState(), createSharedMutations()],
  strict: debug
});
```

when I try to dispatch actions in App.vue

```
 created() {
    const userInDb = UserCotroller.getUser();
    this.$store.disptach("setUser", userInDb);
}
```

I get
`"TypeError: this.$store.disptach is not a function"`

How do I use vuex in this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo there:

```
created() {
    const userInDb = UserCotroller.getUser();
    this.$store.disptach("setUser", userInDb);
}
```

change this to:

```
created() {
    const userInDb = UserCotroller.getUser();
    this.$store.dispatch("setUser", userInDb);
}
```

you wrote `disptach` instead of the correct one `dispatch`